# How do I prevent UIGraphicsImageRenderer.image() from crashing when using UIImage.draw() to draw a large image into the context?

Tags: ios, swift, image, core-graphics, uigraphicsimagerenderer

Working in Swift, I am trying to implement some cropping and other simple edits to full resolution photos for my iOS app. However, when I try to draw a full size image into the context, it crashes due to memory problems.

I wanted to use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer.image()` and keep them as `UIimage`s because the user might add an image not taken by the iPhone camera, and I was having trouble with orientation. I'm assuming I will need to use a `CGimage` or something instead to fix this problem, but would love some ideas about what I'm doing incorrectly.

Here is the relevant code. The canvas size is set by the user choosing a quality of export, the largest being 4000 x 4000. The crash is happening when the `UIImage` (which is stored in the class this function is in) is the size of a full resolution iPhone photo file of 4032 x 3024.

```
if let loadedImage = uiImage {
  let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: canvasSize)
  
  let img = renderer.image(){ ctx in
    // create background
    let rectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: canvasWidth, height: canvasHeight)
    ctx.cgContext.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
    ctx.cgContext.addRect(rectangle)
    ctx.cgContext.drawPath(using: .fill)
    
    //draw in image
    loadedImage.draw(in: photoRect)
    
  } // end renderer.image
  
  uiImage = img
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` uses **point size**.

Assuming you're running this on a `@3x` screen scaled device, you are actually trying to generate an image that is `12,000 x 12,000` **pixels**.

Try it by using a `UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat` with `.scale = 1`:

```
let fmt = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
fmt.scale = 1
        
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: canvasSize, format: fmt)
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much!